# How can I read SD card on ubuntu?

Tags: mount, automount, sd-card

I read various topics here, but wasn't able to find solution for my problem.
I have a sdcard reader on my dell v131 laptop with ubuntu 15.10 installed. I insert my sdcard to reader and cannot find it in media folder.

Output of `dmesg |tail`:

```
[ 2598.842091] usb 4-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0138
[ 2598.842102] usb 4-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2598.842108] usb 4-1.6: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[ 2598.842112] usb 4-1.6: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 2598.842117] usb 4-1.6: SerialNumber: 20090516388200000
[ 2598.848716] ums-realtek 4-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2598.865053] scsi host14: usb-storage 4-1.6:1.0
[ 2599.869001] scsi 14:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 2599.869776] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 2606.258161] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Sdcard in disks:

[image: sdcard in disks]

The /media folder is empty.
Output of `cat /proc/partitions | grep sdb` is empty

How can I acces my sdcard?

**UPD: It seems that my sdcard is dead since format option is grayed out in disks utility. I don't have a second card in touch to verify this. Anyway thank you all for support.**

Comment: Is it listed in disks? (Dash > disks)

Comment: Please see screenshot attached in startpost

Comment: what is the output of `sudo blkid`?

Comment: Are there files to recover in your sd card? Or would you be happy to format the card?

Answer (score 2):

check your partitions inside

```
# cat /proc/partitions
```

If you have there something like

```
# cat /proc/partitions | grep sdb
   8        0  234431064 sdb
   8        1     524288 sdb1
```

You can try to mount sdb1

```
# sudo mkdir /media/sdb1
# sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/sdb1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
sudo mkdir /media/sd
sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/sd
```

Your SD card's contents will now be under `/media/sd/`.

If your SD card has  non-readable filesystem (aka one that Ubuntu doesn't support) you'll have to format it (and lose **all** your data before you can use it).

Comment: Mount command gives `mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb`

Comment: Interesting.  It appears that your SD card has no partitions on it.  Format it as VFAT/FAT32/FAT or something like that and try again.

Comment: Because either it doesn't like that there are no partitions, or something's wrong with your card.  Does this card work in other machines?

Comment: instead of `sdb` use `sdb1`

Comment: Yeah, try that ^ But I'm not so sure it will work